# Realm's Swift module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I just started using Realm 2.0.4 yesterday with Xcode 8 and it worked fine. Today I updated to Xcode 8.1 and it no longer will compile. I get an error saying "Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1."

How can I fix this? I have deleted Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework from the embedded framework table and dropped in the 3.0.1 version, but the issue persists. I have deleted the DerivedData folder and it didn't work.

What do I do? I am not using CocoaPods or Carthage.

Comment: Can you try cleaning the build folder (Xcode "Product" menu while holding down the Option key, then "Clean Build Folder..."?

Comment: I just tried that. It didn't work, but good suggestion.

Comment: Drat. Can you try deleting both frameworks entirely from your project, and then copying in the 3.0.1 versions and re-adding them to the `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` list? If that doesn't work let me know; I'll continue thinking about the problem.

Comment: That seemed to fix it. I had already done that multiple times, but maybe cleaning the build folder helped too. I'm now getting a bash error but I'll figure that out separately. If you'd like to make an answer that I can mark as correct that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for future reference, a bunch of things that you can try:

- Clean the build folder (Go to the Xcode `Product` menu while holding down the Option key, then choose `Clean Build Folder...`)
- Completely reinstall Realm by deleting the framework files from the project, copying them in again, and re-adding them to the `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` project settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot Austin!