# Realm issue with Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I've just updated Xcode using Swift 3.1. While waiting for Realm to update their library, just wondering if someone has a temporary workaround for this issue.

> Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1: RealmSwift.framework

EDIT:

@matt, @bdash, I followed the instruction, removed the old libraries and added new supporting swift 3.1. I got this error

> Showing All Issues Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4

Any idea?

Comment: Keep using the older version of Xcode? Multiple versions of Xcode can coexist just fine (but don't run them at the same time).

Comment: However, here's a useful idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40732325/341994

Comment: (Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731926/realms-swift-module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-1 but I am not competent to judge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Realm Swift v2.5.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v2.5.0), released earlier this week, contains a precompiled framework binary for Swift 3.1. No waiting required.

Comment: please take a look at my EDIT. Any update for Swift 3.1? I tried removing frameworks and using CocoaPods but it didn't help.

Comment: I answered your original question. If you now have a different issue you should ask it in a new question.

Comment: I filed a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304336/realm-for-swift-3-1-command-failed-due-to-signal-illegal-instruction-4 Please help if you have a solution. Thanks