# How to build Swift 3 project on Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift4, xcode9

[Xcode 9 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html) says that Swift 3 compilation is supported:

> **One compiler for Swift 4 and Swift 3**, Swift 4 and Swift 3 targets can be compiled together in the same project.

I have installed Xcode 9 beta.
But when I press Build it shows bunch of errors. Are some special preparations need to do when use Swift 3 in Xcode 9?

UPD:
[image: Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0]

Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0

Comment: What error did you get? Normally, when you open an project created with Xcode 8.3.2 in Xcode 9 beta, it detects right version of Swift (Swift 3.x) and compiles correctly. Anyway, do you have Xcode 8.3.x installed?

Comment: For anyone driving by, you can still download Xcode 9 at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ (it may only be available to paid devs though, not sure)

Answer (score 62):

Select the target, goto `Build Settings > Swift Language Version`:

[image]

Comment: this didn't help =((

Comment: When in the heck did Swift 3.2 come in? Did it come with Xcode 8.3.3? I don't see it at https://swift.org/download/#releases

Comment: Yes, @ChrisPrince; Swift 3.2 came along in Xcode 8.3. It's interesting that 3.2 doesn't show on [Swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#releases). Weird...

Comment: Swift 3.2 is Swift 3.1 connected to the iOS 11 SDK.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.2 and there is no Swift 3.2 option available in drop down. So what needs to be done?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Use an older version of Xcode on an older system or migrate the code manually.

Answer (score 11):

All the above answers are answering the wrong question. When using Xcode 9, you are using the Swift 4 compiler (even if you are using it to compile Swift 3 code) to fix this, recompile using the appropriate compiler/Xcode.

If you are trying to do this via commandline, you can use `sudo xcode-select -switch` to switch between xcode versions. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

## Update for Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2

#### Swift 3, 4, and 4.2 targets can coexist and link together.

> You decide when and if you’d like to migrate on a per-target basis
> when it makes sense for your project. While migrating to Swift 4.2 is
> definitely encouraged, it’s not an all-or-nothing process, as Swift 3,
> 4, and 4.2 targets can coexist and link together.

#### Different cocoapod and different project version can also coexist.

You wish to have different cocoapod version as compared to your project version then you should make following changes at the end of your pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    print "Setting the default SWIFT_VERSION to 4.2\n"
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['SomeTarget-iOS', 'SomeTarget-watchOS'].include? "#{target}"
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to 3.0\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        else
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to Undefined (Xcode will automatically resolve)\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings.delete('SWIFT_VERSION')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Sometimes even after you run pod update your xcode forcefully update your cocoapod's project version, then in that case select cocoapod pod project and change the swift version in the build settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue - (I installed pod which swift version was 3x and my project's swift version was Swift 4. So I got so many compiler errors. Later I changed the Swift version form 4 to 3.2 and tried to build project, again I got compiler errors. I think that happen because of I run pod install while my project was in Swift 4.)

- First you need to change the "Swift language version" from build settings.
- If you have installed any pod then changing only "Swift Language Version" won't help. You may need to run pod install for the project.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 9 needs the framework to be built with Swift 3.2 or higher. Go to https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger and click Download ZIP. Open the xcodeproj in Xcode 9. Press ⌘B. CleanroomLogger.framework turns from red to black. Drag the framework into your project. See related question: [Realm issue with Swift 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152216/realm-issue-with-swift-3-1)

[image: build it]

Comment: this does not do a generic build. If you build the framework like this, it will only work for iOS devices, (you have generic iOS device build target), and it will not work with the simulator.