# Should I use Swift 4 migration tool for pods?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4

I've got many warnings for pods which are included to my project. I've already updated them, but I still have option to use migration tool. Should I use it or I should wait when developers will upgrade library? How it works?

[image]

Comment: You should wait until those libraries supports Swift 4. Isn't there an option in the project to support older versions of Swift?

Comment: Since those are external libraries, you should wait for the new version to be release: if you start changing something, you will need to apply the same fix again every time you decide to update them.

Reading the list, those are well known libraries: owners are probably already working on them, but you can contribute making a fix and creating a pull requests, so your work will help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Swift pods have already a Swift 4 version, but not on the master branch. Fortunately, you can specify branches when listing the pods in the podfile.
Overwrite RxSwift, RxCocoa & RxGesture in your podfile like below:

`pod "RxSwift", :git => "https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git", :branch => "rxswift4.0-swift4.0"`

`pod "RxCocoa", :git => "https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git", :branch => "rxswift4.0-swift4.0"`

`pod "RxGesture", :git => "https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxGesture.git", :branch => "swift-4"`

But in this case RxGesture's swift-4 branch requires RxSwift 3.6.
So you either wait until the official swift 4 releases or compile your project with multiple swift versions:
[How to build Swift 3 project on Xcode 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389591/how-to-build-swift-3-project-on-xcode-9)