# Adding framework manually - Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom framework (not using pods or carthage). Swift on my mac is 4.0.3. On compiling the project I get the error :

> Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.3

I know this topic has been discussed quite a bit like [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389591/how-to-build-swift-3-project-on-xcode-9). However, in my case the, the framework has been added manually.

Comment: Please check this post: [Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1)

Comment: @Kevinosaurio : Already checked. Removing derived data doesn't help. Also, my Xcode is latest.

Comment: is you Xcode **Tools** 9.1?

Comment: @Kevinosaurio : Left with no option other than downloading Xcode 9.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recompile the framework with swift 4.0.3 before adding it to your project.